# laravel pagination with DB::select

Tags: laravel, pagination

How to get total count of the query result in pagination results.

```
ex:$result=DB::select("select * from table");
$pagination = new Paginator($result, $resultsPerPage, $currentPage);
```

Above one gives me resultsperpage and current page but how to take total count.?

Fourth argument requires as array type i tried it but its not working.
i need result like this.

```
 {
        "total": 32,
        "per_page": 4,
        "current_page": 1,
        "last_page": 8,
        "next_page_url":  "http://192.168.0.117/projects/videoSharingApp/VSA/public/me/videos?page=2",
        "prev_page_url": null,
        "from": 1,
        "to": 4,
    }
```

Comment: Are you using the results in a blade file or returning the results in a `JSON` response? Can you show the code from your controller?

Comment: Above one is from  json response ,if i use this $pagination = new Paginator($result, $resultsPerPage, $currentPage); i get the above result without "total" in json result. i just need to total in my json list.